# Challenge : Finding the right minimized order of points.

Tags: logic, coordinate-systems, python

There's stolen diamonds in a lot of different places. The places are on a coordinate system (x,y) where each place is named after a number and have an d-time for example:

```
Name  X  Y  dT
1   283 248 0
2   100 118 184
3   211 269 993
4   200 200 948
5   137 152 0
6   297 263 513
7   345 256 481
8   265 212 0
9   185 222 840 
10  214 180 1149
11  153 218 0
12  199 199 0
13  289 285 149
14  177 184 597
15  359 192 0
16  161 207 0
17  94  121 316
18  296 246 0
19  193 122 423
20  265 216 11
```

dT stand for due time and it's given for each place, which is the fixed time when we need to get the diamonds back before the thief move their hideout away/sell it out.

Starting point is always 1.

I (the police ) need to visit all places only once and get the diamonds back ( visiting each place means you get the diamonds) such that the total delay is minimized. Distance is calculated with Euclidean distance rounded to its closest integer. The arrival time for each places is calculated as in distance + previous distance. The delay for each place is arrival-due and the total delay is the sum of the delays between places.

If I (the police) can get the diamonds before the due time of that place, then the delay is equal to 0; otherwise, the delay equals the difference between the time of arrival and due time of the place.

My mission is to find the right order in which the police can visit each place once that minimizes the delay for two larger instances.

I think I'm pretty much close to an answer myself but I feel something is missing I would be more than grateful if someone can explain me the math, the way and the logic to solve it as it's absolutely impossible to try all permutations.

Extra :
I wrote a code in python where it calculate everything for you ( so you can try it out to check your order ), the only thing missing is the way to find the right order which I hope someone can help me to get a better understanding of.

PS: don't forget to import your data.txt ( the list up )

```
#------------------------------------------------------------------------

poss=[(1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13,14,15,16,17,18,19,20)] # the order

here=[]
for p in range(len(poss)):
    tempos=[]
    for o in range(len(index)):
        point=poss[p][o]
        valuez=order[point-1]
        tempos.append(valuez)
    here.append(tempos)

#//DUE//

due =[[item[b][3] for b in range(len(index))] for item in here]

#//DISTANCE//

x_ = [[item[b][1] for b in range(len(index))] for item in here]
y_ = [[item[b][2] for b in range(len(index))] for item in here]
z = [list(zip(x_[a],y_[a])) for a in range(len(x_))]

dis = []
for aa in range(len(poss)) :
    tempor=[]
    for i in range(len(index)-1):
        firstpoint = z[aa][i]
        secondpoint = z[aa][i+1]
        distance = round(np.linalg.norm(np.array(secondpoint)-np.array(firstpoint)))
        distance = int(distance)
        tempor.append(distance)
    dis.append(tempor)


#//ARRIVAL TIME//
#Arrival time is the sum of the pv distance.

arrival = []
for v in range(len(poss)):
    forone = [0,dis[v][0],]
    for r in range(len(index)-2):
        sumz = dis[v][r+1] + forone[r+1]
        sumz = int(sumz)
        forone.append(sumz)
    arrival.append(forone)

#//DELAY//

delay=[]
for d in range(len(poss)) :
    tempo=[]
    for q in range(len(index)):
        v=arrival[d][q]-due[d][q]
        if arrival[d][q] <= due[d][q]:
            tempo.append(0)
        else :
            tempo.append(v)
    delay.append(tempo)

#//ORDER//
#goal is to find the right order that minimizes the delay for two larger instances.

total = [sum(x) for x in delay]
small= min(total)
final=here[total.index(small)]

print(small)
```

Comment: Just a remark: Minimizing the sum of delay need not maximize the number of retrieved diamonds, i.e., it may be better to be slightly late at two places then a bit more late at one and very early at the other ... -- Also, in the special case that $dT=0$ for all places, we have the travelling salesman problem, hence this problem is at least as hard as that

Comment: @HagenvonEitzen Thanks, I have already tried dealing with it as an TSM problem and solving it using many different ways and algorithm but at the end it appeared that my problem is not really with finding the shortest way. It's really all about the math behind it which I wish to understand because I feel it's close but I can't put my finger on it.